# How to play separate audio on headphones and speaker in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, audio, ios5

I'd like to play different sound on headphones and speaker simultaneously in iOS5.

Specifically I'm using headphone output to control R/C servo motors of a robot. 
I'd like to play sound effect through the speaker. Switching between speaker and headphones would not work since robot is self balancing and need continuos headphone output to balance.

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think its possible...I downloaded the Djay app which has this issue as well - they advise on buying a splitter so you could listen to headphones while hearing on external speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently.  iOS only exposes one stereo audio route to an app via any public API on stock devices.  You will have to use another connectivity method to get the second audio output, such as a MFi device, wifi, gamekit to a second iPhone, etc.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that. All of my experiments failed. Quite likely there is only one DAC that's then routed to either headphones or speaker.